# Logging switch realization

Tags: java, android

This code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private final boolean logging = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.logging);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if(logging) Log.d("my_log", "some text here");

        // some onCreate code...
    }
}
```

generates NullPointerException.

But this one:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final boolean logging = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.logging);
        if(logging) Log.d("my_log", "some text here");

        // some onCreate code...
    }
}
```

Does not.

The main idea to switch logging in entire application with a boolean resource.

I can successfully declare this variable for every function in class, but can it be done for entire class just once?

Comment: editet question to focus on the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting value to string resource, I used static variable in special class.

```
public class constants {

public static final boolean logging = true;

}
```

so it can be accessed from any activity:

```
private boolean logging = constants.logging;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a proper logging framework?

If you use the slf4j API you can write stuff like

```
log.debug("A={}, B={}", a, b)
```

where the switch is externally set in a well-documented way whether to generate a log statement or not.  Also the slf4j {}-construct allows delaying the call to a.toString() and b.toString() until *after* the logging framework has decided that the log message actually needs to be generated.

slf4j is an API.  You have several backends to choose from.  For starters you can just pick the "simple" backend.

See http://slf4j.org/manual.html for an introduction.

Comment: Thank you. Im using android.util.Log framework, you proposing me a facade for the same framework. To implement slf4j i have to rewrite a lot of code. Lets keep things simple. I need just a globally set variable.